# How to change the class of an element based on the URL of the page

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have a navigational side-bar implemented in my webpage. I have several links inside this side-bar and only one is active based on the webpage. E.g. if the URL is /Instructional_Activities, I would like to change the link's class for instructional activities to active. My html code looks like:

```
<ul class="nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('dash-form').submit()">
                    <i class="pe-7s-graph"></i>
                    <p>Dashboard</p>
                    <form id="dash-form" action="/dashBoard" method="POST">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        <input type="hidden" value="test" name="generic">
                    </form>
                </a>
            </li>



            <li>

                <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit();">
                    <i class="pe-7s-note2"></i>
                    <p class='simple-text'>Instructional Activities Report</p>
                    <form id="form-id" method="POST" action="/Instructional_Activities">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        <input type="hidden" value="test" name="generic">
                    </form>

                </a>
            </li>
```

I would like to make the appropriate link to a class of "active" based on the URL of the page. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `is()` method. For example:

```
<p class="{{ request()->is('Instructional_Activities') ? 'active' : 'simple-text' }}">
```

Comment: I usually return a `$page` variable from the controller/function that handle these routes, and do a compare: `<p class="{{ $page == "thisPage" ? "active" : "" }}">...</p>`

Comment: Thank you so much! So something like this would work?
<li class="{{request()->is('Instructional_Activities') ? 'active' : ' ' }}">
assuming I don't want to have an alternative class given?

Comment: @Muhammad sure you can use `''` if you don't want to add any class.

Comment: Yea it works perfectly, thanks for this solution again!

Answer (score 0):

Use path name to get the url part excluding the domain:

```
window.location.pathname
```

Then link through the items to find the right one , assuming you only have one nav bar:

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav li');

for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
     var item = listItems[i];

     if (item.textContent == myUrlPart) {
         item.classList.add('active');
         break;
     }
}
```

Suggestions:

- add a id for the nav bar, so you can use a more refined querySelectorAll.
- Use a span for the path names, and give this span a class so you can compare the text better